# Como acessar prop.getProperty a partir de qualquer Classe do Projeto

Tags: java

Criei uma classe "`Messages`" e coloquei o Método `public Properties getProp()` dentro dela, pois desejo acessar o arquivo `config.properties` a partir de qualquer outra classe do meu projeto.

```
/**
 * @author Alang
 * Criado em 18/05/2017
 */
package com.pub.Utilities;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Messages {

    public Properties getProp() throws IOException
    {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("../PubProject/properties/config.properties");
        props.load(file);
        return props;

    }

}
```

O problema que está ocorrendo é que eu não sei como fazer isso. Então como já tentei várias formas sempre da um erro diferente.

Por exemplo eu criei uma outra classe chamada: `public class Utilities {...}` e dentro desta classe possuo vários métodos.

Como eu posso carregar o valor do parametro `Config.strBrowserType` que está no arquivo `config.properties`, dentro deste método `getTitle()` que faz parte da classe `Utilities`?

Aqui está minha classe Utilities com apenas o método `getTitle(String strTestStep)`.

```
package com.pub.Utilities;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

/**
 * @author Alang
 *
 */
public class Utilities {

    //*** INSTACES  *****************************
    Properties prop = getProp();

    //*** VARIABLES *****************************
    private WebDriver wd;


    public void getBrowserTitle(String strTestStep){

        String strExpectedTitle = prop.getProperty("Config.strBrowserType");
        String strActualTitle = wd.getTitle();

        if (strExpectedTitle.equals(strActualTitle){
            System.out.println(strTestStep + " - PASSED: Application was loaded according expected");
        }else{
            System.out.println(strTestStep + " - FAILED: Application wasn't loaded according expected");
        }

    }

}
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Você não consegue acessar o metodo em qualquer lugar ou o não consegue ler a configuração do arquivo ?

Comment: Eu consigo ler o conteúdo do arquivo, não consigo acessar o método a partir de uma outra classe. Eu queria que o método getProp que encontra-se dentro da classe Messages abaixo, fosse acessível em qualquer outra classe.

public class Messages {

public Properties getProp() throws IOException
{

    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("../PubProject/properties/config.properties");
    props.load(file);
    return props;

}
}

Se eu colocar as chamada dentro da mesma classe onde está o getProp ai funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras:

1º Maneira - Static

Deixar o seu metodo `static`

```
public static Properties getProp() throws IOException
```

utiliza-lo em qualquer lugar da aplicação desta maneira

```
Messages.getProp();
```

Desvantagem: Toda vez que você chamar este metodo você estará criando objetos na memória (Properties e FileInputStream) desnecessariamente, então sugiro o 2º Maneira

2º Maneira - Singleton

```
public final class Messages {

      private Properties props = null;

public synchronized static Properties getProp() throws IOException {
    if(props == null) {
        props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("../PubProject/properties/config.properties");
        props.load(file);
        return props;
    }
    return props;

}
}
```

Para utilizar é da mesma forma.

```
Messages.getProp();
```

Comment: Se você puder explicar o `synchronized` e o `static` seria interessante para a sua resposta

Comment: Olá Erick... bom dia.

Para utilizar em outra classe eu estou fazendo o seguinte:

        Instancio a classe Messages na classe onde quero usar
 //*** INSTANCES  ************************************************
 Messages wd = new Messages();

 wd.getProp();

Seria isso mesmo?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Não precisa criar uma intancia, é so utilizar Messager.getProp();

Comment: Funcionou... tudo certo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se te ajudou pode marcar a resposta como aceita =)